# Multer is not getting the file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload image but i don't know why is is not working. I tried many times tried searching solution but still i am unable to find any solution.
Please help Here is my code

> Routes

```
const router = express.Router();
const validation = [
  body("title").trim().isLength({ min: 7 }),
  body("content").trim().isLength({ min: 5 }),
];

router.get("/", postController.getAllPost);

router.get("/:postId", postController.getPostDetail);
router.post("/", validation, postController.createNewPost);1
```

> postController.js

```
exports.createNewPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error("Validation failed, entered data is incorrect");
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  // if (!req.file) {
  //   const error = new Error("No Image provided");
  //   error.statusCode = 422;
  //   throw error;
  // }
  const { title, content } = req.body;
  
  console.log("reqfile", req.file);  <-- i am getting undefined here
  const imageUrl = req.file.path;
  const post = new Post({
    title,
    content,
    imageUrl,
    creator: {
      username: "Aditya",
    },
  });
  post
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Post created successfully",
        post: result,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};
```

> app.js

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log("destFile", file);  <-- nothing gets logged here
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log("file", file);  <-- nothing gets logges here
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimeType === "image/png" ||
    file.mimeType === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimeType === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

// To parse Incoming data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  multer({
    storage: fileStorage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
  }).single("image")
);
```

> Here is how i am making request

[image: request image]

Answer (score 0):

OKI then.

```
-src/
--routes.js
--app.js
--controller.js
```

let's imagine our project looks like that oki.
on yow `routes.js` youll have some like

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import {
    uploadInePics,
} from "./controller";
const ots = multer({});
const inMemory = multer.memoryStorage();
const uploadStrategy = multer({ storage: inMemory, limits: { files: 5 }, preservePath: true }).array("file", 5);

export function picsRoutes () {
    const api = Router();

    api.route("/api/yow-path").get(getMyPics).post(uploadStrategy,uploadMyPics);

    return api;
}
```

on yow `controller.js`
you can see them pics at `req.files`

```js
export async function uploadMyPics (req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
        const account = await getToken(req.headers);

        for (const file of req.files) {
         // do the magic <3
        }
        return res.sendStatus(201)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.sendStatus(503)
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added body parser still it is giving same error

Comment: I Changed the answare. hope it helps